# Putty - Automation process

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I'm having some trouble performing an automated PuTTy instance.
I have a code being created from a Excel VBA process whose output is the username, password, and a series of commands including cd, vi, and perl.

Although its working in portions, I'm unable to run this all together.
I wasn't able to find a proper *wait* instance (sleep is not working) between commands and ends up being a huge mess.

I know that **sleeps** is not the best approach, but helps to picture the current situation.
Also don't know how to create a proper text editing instance and if bash would be a much better way to do so.

See code below:

```
username
password
sleep 3
sudo su
password
cd /data/filebase; sleep 3
vi host.txt
:imap ii <Esc>
:1,$d
i
referenceinformacion
ii
:wq!
sleep 3; cd ..; cd ..
perl runaway.pl -d filebase -u username -w password
perl fetch.pl; sleep 3
exit; sleep 1; exit
```

The output should come clean, but its dragging all the lines across the window.
The idea behind this is that from excel you should be able to have the code ready to be pasted into putty by only login into the server.

ie. open putty, put hostname and port, and once open you just paste the entire code which includes all the stuff together

Comment: Does Excel need to be tagged? From what I understand, your question/issue is with Putty/Linux, not Excel?

Answer (score 0):

make a bash script and use sshpass to pass the password to ssh, will make it even easier (less input) than what you are trying, pass the params to the bash script and access them with $1 $2 etc

Comment: I did thought of having Putty to autologin with **putty.exe -ssh  host -u user -pw pass** and then store two .sh in the home so my code afer successfully login would reduced to:
`command1.sh`
`information that would be stored in **vi** but I would use **sed**`
`command2.sh`
`exit`